# Probability of deviation from average

Tags: probability, mean

I would like to know how likely it is that a randomly sampled result is 14 percentage points above the actual average.

I have 658 households, of which 6% are supposed to be rich. A random sample of 60 households returned 20% rich households. How likely is it that this was just a freak of probability or rather that either the sampling was not truly random or the initial supposition of 6% simply wrong?

I would very much appreciate some help on this.
Thanks.

Comment: It comes down to what "it" refers to. You have noticed something about your data, evidently related to the difference between 20% and 6%. However, it's highly likely that any random sample of 60 out of 658 will yield a fraction that isn't exactly 6%. Thus, *you must characterize the nature of the difference that caused you to react to these data.*  What it usually comes down to in practice is whether the *magnitude* of the difference got your attention or the *direction* of the difference (above or below), or both. Because this is a *post hoc* hypothesis, beware of overinterpreting any test!

Comment: Ok. Well, the nature is that the measured value is more than 3 times higher than the "predicted" one. That makes me naturally suspicious.  If it was 50% higher, I would readily accept that due to a small sample size such deviations can happen. But what are the chances of that happening in this case? I mean in theory I could have 66% rich in my sample, if I got all of them. But the chances seem very improbable. I want to know what are the chances of getting this increased figure. Is it still in the realm of "realistically not unlikely" or is it something that should make me perk-up?

Comment: Maybe I did not explain well that the 20% came out of a resurvey, so are not a sampling of paper values but of the real people. So, what makes me wonder is the original source claiming 6% having supposedly sampled all households and my data, having only sampled about 10% of households.

Comment: You are operating in the realm of "I saw something that surprised me, what are the chances of that?" They are far greater than you think.  Formulating your statistical hypothesis after seeing the data leads to terrible problems: see [HARKing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HARKing).  It's something to be aware of.  That's going to be crucial to formulating your question and obtaining a valid, useful answer.

Comment: Without surprise no science. 
"They are far greater than you think." Ok! So, how big exactly, that is my question. I am not posing any hypothesis at all. I do not want a significance. I want a probability. only. The chance to win in lottery can be clearly calculated, so it must be easy to tell me what the chance of this outcome is,

Comment: A probability or chance is more than a calculation: it is associated with an *event.*  When that event is constructed *post hoc,* there is usually no way to compute its probability because the mathematical models required do not apply.